# Python-based statistical model to auto-detect coordinates of Form fields on a PDF

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I want to detect coordinates of a fill-able PDF forms, more precisely bounding box coordinates of a text-box where a particular text field (String) is going to be placed.

Currently I'm following a hard-coded Python-Pdfminer approach using LTTBox to detect the coordinates based on certain string presence.

Example:

```
def identifyTextboxes(path, fieldName, fieldType):
    # reading the file and setting prams
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    pages = PDFPage.get_pages(fp)

    # defining key-terms of custodian:
    names=["Name of entity:", "Name of Investor (Please Print or Type)", "Print Name of Entity", "Name of Prospective Investor ", 
    "Investor's Name", "Name (the “Applicant” or “We”)", "On Behalf of:", "Name of Business"]

    num_pages = 0
    output = []
    for page in pages:
        temp_dict = {}
        interpreter.process_page(page)
        layout = device.get_result()
        num_pages += 1

        # fetching the coordinates of the text via bbox
        for lobj in layout:
            if isinstance(lobj, LTTextBox):
                (x, y, xw, yh), text = lobj.bbox, lobj.get_text()
                for name in names:
                    ResSearch = re.search(name, text)                
                    if ResSearch:break
                    field='textbox'
            if ResSearch:break
        if ResSearch:
            temp_dict['label'] = fieldName
            temp_dict['type'] = fieldType
            temp_dict["value"] = ''
            temp_dict['group'] = ''
            temp_dict["overlay"] = {'page': num_pages, 'left': (xw)-90, 'top':((y-10)-(yh-y))+90, 'height': 20, 'width':240}
            output.append(temp_dict)
            print(lobj)
    return output
```

In the code above, i detect places where the matching string appears from the list names and define the coordinate of the text-box on the right to the appearance based on LTTBox coordinates and a fixed with, as you can see on the return output['overlay'].

This process is very much hard-coded and fails when any unknown string or situation occurs in a PDF, hence not that robust.

I want to drive a more data driven statistical approach to detect the coordinates of a bounding box via CNN/RNN/CNN+RNN. I have gone through [EAST detector](https://github.com/argman/EAST), but that doesn't seem to solve the problem, so maybe training a more customized network should be perhaps more useful.

Please find the pictures attached for a better understanding if what the current code does.
[image]
[image]

I'm new to ML, i need guidance to construct a network of this kind. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, have you fond a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If the forms are proper PDF AcroForm fields, you can easily find them by just reading the PDF file.

Just look for text like this in your PDF file:

```
7 0 obj
<<
/Type /Annot 
/Subtype /Widget 
/Rect [ 87.539 495.187 139.289 511.890 ] 
/F 4 
/FT /Tx 
/H /N 
/R 0 
/Ff 4194304 
/BS << /W 1 /S /S  >>
/MK <</BC [ 0.267 0.267 0.267 ] /BG [ 0.996 0.839 0.804 ]  >>
/T (name1[first])
/TU (<FE><FF>)
/DV ()
/DA (/F2 9.9 Tf 0.000 g)
/NM (0007-5003)
/M (D:20181012063448)
>>
```

Another example:

```
23 0 obj
<</Type/Annot/Subtype/Widget/F 4
/Rect[165.7 388.3 315.7 402.5]
/FT/Tx
/P 1 0 R
/T(Address 1 Text Box)
/V <FEFF>
/DV <FEFF>
/MaxLen 40
/DR<</Font 6 0 R>>
/DA(0 0 0 rg /F3 11 Tf)
/AP<<
/N 60 0 R
>>
>>
endobj
```

The coordinates of the field are the numbers after `/Rect`, in the sequence left, bottom, right, top.

It could be that the object in question is compressed. In that case you won't see it as text. In such a case I would recommend using `mutool clean -d input.pdf readable.pdf` to decompress all objects in the PDF file, making the file readable with a text editor. `mutool` is a command-line tool that comes with [mupdf](https://www.mupdf.com/index.html).

Comment: But the problem is, the forms are not Acro forms. And probably scanned PDFs are to be considered. More importantly, if you can suggest statistical model based approach? Where there shouldn't be any hard-coded rule of a specific field.